# sharing DAO across queues. separate reads/writes. masstransit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mongodb, messaging, masstransit

I saw an [example](http://pablocastilla.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/mongodbmasstransitasp-net-mvcangularjs/#respond) of how to create `asp.net mvc` application using `masstransit` messaging.

What I do undersatnd:

- `asp.net mvc controllers` are meant to pusblish events;
- whereas responses come from other (`rabbitmq`) queue hosted in a separate assembly via `SignalR`/or any other transport;
- each queue (jobs, db writes, responses) is hosted in a separate console project/windows
  service.

What I don't undersatnd:

- whether separation of reads and writes is necessary?
- the example uses `mongodb` which I still can use. So it doesn't get problematic to even separate reads and writes. But what about `SQL Server/EF`? How would you build/share db access across multiple assemblies? Should each queue assembly host its own `DbContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use SQL Server and EF then yes, each process would have it's own `DbContext` instance to access the the database. It would be the same shared type across all processes. That's not a problem at all. I would define the EF domain in a shared assembly though. Breaking apart reads and writes isn't an issue at all.

Breaking apart reads and writes isn't really necessary, esp. at first. However, it can become needed as you scale up and have other concerns mixed in or additional scale. Breaking apart reads and writes is just a useful tool in modeling the software you need to write. It's not a requirement at all.